# Scrolling issues when the `wrap` option is set

Tags: cursor-movement, terminal, normal-mode, scrolling

I find myself dealing with this issue every time the `wrap` option is active (in my particular case whenever I'm working with markdown files).

What happens is that, while scrolling up and down the buffer with `j` and `k`, the wrapped lines of text (visually forming a paragraph) at the far top and far bottom don't scroll smoothly (i.e. one by one) out of screen. Instead, whole paragraphs disappear and reappear abruptly from and into view, making for a disorienting and annoying effect.

I think a GIF will explain better what happens. Here, I'm just pressing `k` repeatedly to scroll upwards. Keep an eye on the paragraph near the bottom!

[image: ugh]

I got used to this behaviour because I didn't think it was fixable, but then I realized that doesn't happen with physical lines and `wrap` unset.

Is there a way to tell Vim to scroll out of screen by visual lines instead of physical ones?

ps: Yes, I've mapped my `j` and `k` to `gj` and `gk`.

Comment: This might help you: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/visual-scrolling-visual-c-e-and-c-y-across-wrapped-lines

Answer (score 8):

That is an issue, that has been often requested but never been implemented. So no, there is no possibility for a better and smoother scrolling, once the lines wrap.

**Update**: This is no longer entirely true. See [@Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich)s [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/42151/71) for the status as of 2023

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to where this issue has being discussed? I'd like to know more.

Comment: [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/TOscNwiwy5E/eyl3dZOrsL0J) or [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/AmMWxM0dIIA/-97E3jal3IsJ)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for:

```
set display=lastline
```

See `:help 'display'`.

Comment: That *kinda* worked but I still don't get the smooth, line-by-line scrolling I get when `wrap` is unset. The behavior now looks actually inconsistent: more gradual (but still not line-by-line) scrolling while going up, and abrupt paragraph appearance when going down (see [GIF](http://i.imgur.com/AZn3kh0.gifv)).

Comment: Too bad, cause reading the help page that really looked like my option.

Comment: According to `:help 'scrolljump'` I think that the minimum jump you can get is one line when the cursor moves off-screen. But with `wrap` set as in your case, one line may occupy multiple screen lines.

Comment: this solved my issue, `set display=lastline` when on screen it wasnt displaying last line, it was acting wonky, and content wasnt scrolling and displaying with cursor.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is hope!

A new option [`'smoothscroll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smoothscroll%27) was added to Vim [in version 9.0.0640](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f6196f424474e2a9c160f2a995fc2691f82b58f9), to allow nicer scrolling with [soft-wrapped](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27) lines.

The bad news is that it currently<sup>1</sup> doesn't support the `gj` and `gk` commands:

> **NOTE:** only partly implemented, currently works with [CTRL-E](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-E), [CTRL-Y](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-Y) and scrolling with the mouse.

<sub>1: As of around May 2023</sub>

Comment: No wonder `j` and `k` are not supported, they are unrelated to scrolling.

Comment: @romainl Like the OP, I have j/k mapped to gj/gk. Updated my answer.