# Visual scrolling/visual <C-e> and <C-y> across wrapped lines?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, scrolling, multiple-lines, mouse

This has been [asked on stackoverflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369021/in-vim-how-to-scroll-continuously-by-screen-lines-when-wrapping-is-enabled), but it seems it still has no solution. Perhaps that has changed with Vim 8.0.

I'd like to be able to scroll (i.e. scroll-wheel, or `<C-y>`/`<C-e>` in normal mode) by **visual lines** when line-wrapping is enabled, rather than by line number. This can come in handy for text documents (in my case, LaTeX files).

Any chance Vim 8.0 allows this somehow? Or can anyone suggest a vimscript `function` hack that might accomplish the same thing?

Comment: not possible as far as i know

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt was wondering though if there was some way to cook up a vimscript `function` that remaps `<C-y>` and `<C-e>` (in this case, we'd want the map to be recursive/global, so would use `map`). Maybe there's some way to determine "how many wrapped lines does this line have?" Seems like the fact that Vim gives the option to display partial lines going on/offscreen implies there must be some convoluted way to do it.

Comment: Not really, because Vim does not allow to only display partial rows. That's why smooth scrolling does not really work well in Vim. And there is nothing, VimL functions can do against it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt well actually it sort of can with `set display=lastline`, but I see what you mean; windows must always **start** on the first wrapped line of a line. Seems to me that aspect is what makes this impossible.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt FWIW I came up with a hack that does (for example) **as close to** half-page scrolling as possible across wrapped lines, and prevents the cursor from jumping around. I now absolutely depend on it for editing LaTeX documents. Check out the answer below.

Comment: Correction: the viewport does **not** have to start at the first visual line of a wrapped "line". The counterexample is: make a very long wrapped line (e.g. that takes up 100 visual lines and goes beyond the viewport), then keep pressing `gj`, and we see that the viewport moves down one visual line at a time and the first, then second, etc. visual lines of the wrapped "line" move out of view. So the capability is already there. But how to bind it to scrolling machinery is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've released a [vim plugin](https://github.com/lukelbd/vim-scrollwrapped) that pretty closely matches this behavior.

Instead of scrolling by exactly `N` lines, this maps `<C-u>`, `<C-d>` (half window) and `<C-j>`, `<C-k>` (quarter window) to scroll *as close to `N` lines as possible due to the wrapped lines*, then moves the cursor back to the original relative line position in the Vim window. To match the vim behavior, if the top or bottom of the window are on line 1 or the final line, scrolling does *not* preserve the original cursor location and the cursor starts moving up the window until reaching the boundary.

This plugin also introduces a `:WrapToggle` command (mapped to `<Leader>w`) that toggles wrapping on and off, and swaps the various `j`, `gj`, `k`, `gk` maps so that the basic motion commands are *always* with respect to visual lines, and the `g` prefixed maps are with respect to actual lines when line wrapping is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

A new option [`'smoothscroll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smoothscroll%27) was added to Vim [in version 9.0.0640](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f6196f424474e2a9c160f2a995fc2691f82b58f9), to allow nicer scrolling with [soft-wrapped](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27) lines.

As of around May 2023, the documentation includes this proviso:

> **NOTE:** only partly implemented, currently works with CTRL-E, CTRL-Y and scrolling with the mouse.