# How to visually scroll one line at the time with long lines?

Tags: neovim

Not even sure I can describe this well, but I work in markdown with one line per paragraph, due to some issues that are outside of my control, and i would like the screen to scroll down following the *visual* lines rather than the *actual* lines. In markdown I have remapped <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, but when I get to the end of the screen the whole document jumps several lines down, breaking the flow of reading.

I would basically like to be able to emulate normal scroll behavior with its <kbd>g</kbd>-cousins and I don't even know where to start.

System: ArchLinux, neovim, termite

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't currently possible. See this question's answers and the links for more details: [Scrolling issues when the \`wrap\` option is set](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/scrolling-issues-when-the-wrap-option-is-set). You may also be interested in the plugin described in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11383/343)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The plugin you mentioned is interesting indeed, but doesn't really solve my issue. Crossing fingers that this will (eventually) be resolved upstream...

Comment: What's curious is if you `:set display=lastline` and then use `ctrl-e` instead of `j` to scroll screen lines upwards you don't get the same "pop" of multiple lines appearing at once. If you're just reading, as opposed to editing, maybe this is an adequate workaround...

Comment: Hmmm... that doesn't seem to work on my system. `ctrl-e` still scrolls by real lines and not visual lines, producing nice little jumps.