# Remove 'jumps' when moving to last and first line in Vim

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling, multiple-lines

I have the `display` option set to `lastline` so that the last line is shown even if all it doesn't fit on the window. When moving down visual lines with `gj` to the last line that is only partially visible, vim seems to scroll the window down extra visual lines so that the whole line is visible. This leads to a 'jumpy' scrolling, and it is especially obnoxious if a logical line spans across many visual lines.

For reference, a gif of the 'jump' when moving to the last line:
[image: Screen cap gif showing the 'jump']

Similar behavior occurs when moving above to a logical line that does not fit in one visual line.

How would I go about removing this 'jump' that vim does to fit the line on the window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrolling issues when the \`wrap\` option is set](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4507/scrolling-issues-when-the-wrap-option-is-set)